# How to solve FeathersJS front date querying with NeDB

Tags: date, feathersjs, nedb

On a front application using Feathers client, I'm trying to filter data by date:

```js
rides = await client.service('rides').find({
  query: {
    date: {
      ...past ? { $lt: new Date().getTime() } : { $gte: new Date().getTime() },
    },
    $sort: {
      date: past ? 1 : -1,
    },
  },
}).then(result => result.data);
```

This is not working, giving me zero result.

I found on an [official issue](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-reactive/issues/62#issuecomment-469950236) this is because the query is passed as a string and NeDB needs a Date instance.

This hack on the feathers api hook confirms the issue:

```js
// On find.before hook
if (params.query && params.query.date.$gte) {
  params.query.date.$gte = new Date(params.query.date.$gte);
}
if (params.query && params.query.date.$lt) {
  params.query.date.$lt = new Date(params.query.date.$lt);
}
```

But this is not a reliable solution to build reliable querying on any field.

What is the best way to handle it?

Comment: why are you passing as `.getTime()` from the client?

Comment: @Joe I just followed the official guide: https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/querying.html#lt-lte
But I also tried passing the Date object directly, without a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better generic workaround on global application hooks:

```js
import { HookContext } from '@feathersjs/feathers';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default {
  before: {
    find: [
      (context: HookContext) => {
        const { params } = context;
        const dateFormatRegex = 

        const mapper = (value: any): any => {
          // Recursive call of the mapper
          if (_.isPlainObject(value)) {
            return _.mapValues(value, mapper);
          }
          // String date to Date object transform.
          if (dateFormatRegex.test(value)) {
            return new Date(value);
          }
          return value;
        };

        if (params.query) {
          params.query = _.mapValues(params.query, mapper);
        }
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

And then on the front client, replace `new Date().getTime()` by `new Date().toISOString()`.

It works, but I found this a bit hacky, I'm quit surprised this is not managed by Feathers or NeDB them-self, maybe I'm missing something?